# tlsClientParameters contains keystore password with special character ''+" and it gives error

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, cxf, http-conduit

I am using Apache CXF endpoint with Http Conduit xml for keystore certificate and password with proxy settings. 
It is used for consuming SOAP webservice.
But my certificate contains some special characters eg- '+'
Please suggest some way to incoporate password with special character.

```
So its gives me exception saying -`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters]: Factory method 'createTLSClientParametersFromType' threw exception; nested exception is java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:435)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133)
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSParameterJaxBUtils.getKeyManagers(TLSParameterJaxBUtils.java:306)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(TLSClientParametersConfig.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:217)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:399)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:133)
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:70)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSParameterJaxBUtils.getKeyManagers(TLSParameterJaxBUtils.java:306)
    at org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParametersFromType(TLSClientParametersConfig.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid RSA private key
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.parseKeyBits(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:214)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:343)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:357)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:91)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:75)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:316)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:213)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:372)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:399)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): Redundant length bytes found
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:606)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:569)
    at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getPositiveBigInteger(DerInputStream.java:220)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.parseKeyBits(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:205)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:343)
    at sun.security.pkcs.PKCS8Key.decode(PKCS8Key.java:357)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:91)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.newKey(RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl.java:75)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:316)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(RSAKeyFactory.java:213)`
```